# How to put 2 web apps on the same domain and port using apache as a forward proxy

Tags: apache, proxy, local-storage

I am 2 running webapps on localhost, one on port 80 and one on port 3000.
I would like to use apache as a forward proxy to put these apps on the same domain and port, in order for them the share the same localstorage.

Could anyone tell me how this is done?